# Initialize typedef of int arrray within definition?

Tags: c, initialization, typedef

Doing practice questions for a 1st Year Programming "101" exam. Trying something and I'm not sure its possible.

Q. *Give a type definition suitable for representing the assignment marks for 10 students and initialised all marks to zero.*

As I interpret that the examiner wants the def and initialisation to be done together. Otherwise Id just make a struct and initialize it after.

```
typedef int foobar[10]; //is accepted but is not initialised
typedef int foobar[10] = {0}; //Error " , expected"
typedef int foobar[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //Error " , expected"
```

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting or does initialization have to be done separately?

NB: All the previous questions I could find related to structs where Im specifically looking at an array of int.

Comment: c or c++ pick one here please!

Comment: Perhaps you are expected to use a `class` whose constructor performs a suitable initialisation step? It is hard to tell, given that you've tagged your answer C and C++!

Comment: Apologies, rectified.

Comment: Frankly, the question (that you are working on) is appalling.  In C, you can't provide initializers when you define a `typedef`.  It is not clear from the specification what they mean; does the student have an ID or name that needs to be tracked? Is it for a single assignment or for multiple assignments?  What is the structure going to be used for?  Without more context, I've no clue what the expected answer is.  And, in C you can only mix an initializer with a type definition if you use something like `struct marks { char name[10]; int mark; } marks[10] = { { "him", 10 }, … };`.

Comment: Variable declarations have an initializer,   I'm trying to find any suggestion that a type declaration can have an initializer.   My gut answer is to say no they can't.

Comment: `typedef int typename[10]; typename variable_name = {0};`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll agree with you there, very unclear question. Its from the previous lecturer who is now just a lab assistant who was never very helpful or even communicative. Seems like he copied and pasted each years exam...

BLUEPIXY as above thats the obvious way to do it, but it doesnt accomplish the goal I was asking about.

Comment: Honestly, I'd answer with something along the lines of "This is a terribly written question. A type definition (a.k.a. "typedef") cannot be initialized, so that would be the answer. In the event that it meant, 'Give a type definition suitable for representing the assignment marks for 10 students, **create an object of that type**, and initialize all marks **represented by that object** to zero,' the answer could be `typedef unsigned int marklist[10]; marklist marks = {0};` since no information was provided about any other desired data. Please exclude questions like this in the future."

Answer (score 2):

> **Initialize typedef of int arrray within definition?**
>
> ...
>
> *Give a type definition suitable for representing the assignment marks for 10 students and initialised all marks to zero.*

The title and the question make no sense or at least are incomplete, as it does not mention **what** to initialise. Types cannot be initialised per definition. Only "instantiated" types can be intialised. So either this assingment is unfullfilable, or one needs to assume an implicit instantiation of the type defined.

However, doing the latter, in C one **needs** two steps to achieve this.

1. Define the type:

   ```
   typedef int[10] Marks;
   ```
2. Define the variable using the type defined in 1. and initialise it:

   ```
   Marks marks = {0};
   ```

Comment: The comments above agree with that, cant be done in one go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Give a type definition suitable for representing the assignment
>   marks for 10 students and **initialised** (??) all marks to zero.

The word "initialized" doesn't make sense. I assume they ask you to "initialize" instead.

> Give a type definition suitable for representing the assignment
>   marks for 10 students and **initialise** all marks to zero.

So they ask you to do two things, "give a type definition" and "initialize all marks", preferably in one line of code (?).

What is a type definition? Is it something that has `typedef` in it? I guess not! I understand it as "something that defines a type". For example:

```
struct Marks {int marks[10];};
```

Yeah, this thing defines a type with the ugly name `struct Marks`. Since this doesn't have `typedef` in it, you actually can define a variable of that type, and initialize that variable, all in the same line of code:

```
struct Marks {int marks[10];} stuff = {{0}};
```

Comment: It shall be `... = {{0}};`

Comment: @alk You are right; but I heard that in C, `{0}` is often used as an "idiomatic zero-initialization". `{{0}}` or even `{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}` might be more clear in this case.

Comment: ... and it (`{{0}}`) keeps the compiler from issuing a warning if having been told to be chatty using `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer for C++:

There are very few places in C++ where datatype definitions contain any "value" data. I can only think of a few:

1. Enums
2. Template parameters
3. Function parameters that have default values

Otherwise, data and the data *type* are always separated. You can't specify the initial value of a type in the definition.

Something is confusing about your question: you say

```
typedef int foobar[10]; //is accepted but is not initialised
```

Understand that this is only a datatype definition; there is nothing yet to initialize.

```
foobar x = {0};// this should compile and work fine.
```

But the initialization is done when you instantiate the type, not in the type definition.

Comment: Verify that your answer is valid for C.

Comment: Bleh I started typing when it was marked as C and C++. I'm just going to leave it here in case it helps anyone in C++.